# Multi-level array of structured objects in elasticsearch using jdbc-river

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I'm using elasticsearch(elasticsearch-1.1.1) with jdbc river plugin(1.1.0.2)   I’m trying to achieve multi-level array of structured object.

Following is my data.

```
    _id     |   Column1  |  Column2   |  Column3
------------+------------+------------+------------ 
4702560747  | 4702560747 | 4706318209 | 4816766466
---------------------------------------------------
4702560747  | 4702560747 | 4706318209 | 4816862011
---------------------------------------------------
4702560747  | 4702560747 | 4707978645 | 4816862008
---------------------------------------------------
4702560747  | 4702560747 | 4707978645 | 4816862010
```

I want to json to be generated as follows.

```
{
  "deal": {
    "id": 4702560747,
    "quotes": [
      {
        "quote": {
          "id": 4706318209,
          "lines": [
            {
              "line": {
                "id": 4816766466
              }
            },
            {
              "line": {
                "id": 4816862011
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "quote": {
          "id": 4707978645,
          "lines": [
            {
              "line": {
                "id": 4816862008
              }
            },
            {
              "line": {
                "id": 4816862010
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```